# how can get google search result

Tags: php

How can I get the result of search in Google search, but without using the API.

I've tried many ways, but Google detects the ip server and prints an error.
The function I use:

```
fopen
fsocket
...
```

For example this function can get html from other web sites, but for Google search, Google returns an error.

Is there a way I can get search results from Google?

```
function openpage($ur)
{
  $buf="";  
  $ur=str_replace(" ","+",$ur);

  $fp = fopen($ur, "rb");     
  if ($fp) 
        {
        while(!feof($fp)) $buf=$buf.fgets($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        }
return $buf;    
}
```

Comment: I suggest not doing whatever it is you're trying to do: [5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS)

Comment: Why not use the API? The API is designed for this, so it'd be foolish not to use it.

Comment: Actually, what sarnold said is your answer. There is an API for accessing it and not using the API but automated parsing is against googles terms. Thus you will probably not find help here, help to break the terms.

Comment: From a technological perspective, elaborating what Sebastian said, parsing the Google search result frontend introduces a big overhead. All the markup surrounding the results are useless, potential javascript requests etc would be tedious to parse as well, and furthermore it will be highly error-prone because, depending on your parsing you will have to update the parsing algorithm each time google updates the search result pages markup. API is to prevent all of that hassle.

Comment: I have an good alternate for you @ravi, you dont use this code, you dont use the API, then for sure you can go to this site and get the results
http://www.google.com

Comment: yes google dont agree to get the result by other code. but i see a site,he can get result,by perl (not use api)

Comment: for api you must pay money !!! i search for other alternative!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have done a small project about it before. I used [HTMLagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here is the source you can check it.

https://github.com/serdarb/Google-Results
https://github.com/serdarb/Google-Results/blob/master/frmMain.cs

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection hrefList = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div//ol//li[@class='g']//h3//a");
```

But do not send to many requests... Google asks for a captcha or returns error.